Steps to safely remove files from the history of GIT repository
Background
I have a project of a Drupal site in a GIT repo. I inherited this project and noticed that the repo itself is much bigger than it should be. As this is GIT repo is part of the deployment, I was asked by the hosting company to do something about it.
The problem
My understanding is that just customizations should be part of the repository (configuration, custom modules and theme, working files, etc) so things like Drupal core files, vendor projects, and contributed modules should not be in it.
By executing some commands, I realized that there's a lot of files in my repo that should not be there. Files that at a moment in time, were added to the git before the person responsible at the time realized they should be ignored (added to .gitignore).
The scope
To find out which files I had in my repo I ran the following command
git rev-list --objects --all | \
                         git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | \
                         sed -n 's/^.* blob //p' | \
                         awk '{printf "%.3f MB\t%s\n", $1/1048576, $2}' | \
                         sort -n -k 1 > git-list-file-with-size.txt

The result was a large TXT file (close to 100,000 lines) showing some interesting results..

a bunch of ZIP files from /.composer-cache folder
a bunch on files from folders that should be (or eventually were ) added to .gitignore. Folders like /vendor, /core, /modules/contrib, and themes/contrib

Here are a couple of lines from the TXT file
18.408 MB   vendor/phpstan/phpstan/phpstan.phar
29.474 MB   .composer-cache/files/drupal/core/c9e0b432f7eeb1b6ece89b59f659cf09ab4421f5.zip

It is my understanding that even if these files are not in any actual current state of any branch, they still exist in the repo (in case we have to revert to a position in time when they existed.
From the 100,000 lines ( 90,000 would correspond to those examples mentioned above, i.e., from my understanding, files that should not be in my repo. Is that correct?
The solution
After doing some research, these are the steps I came up with to "clean" the repository:

Install git filter-repo (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), make it executable and move it to the bin folder.
Git clone mirror my repo to a new location in my local environment (git clone --mirror)
Execute git filter-repo, listing all folders and files that should be exclude. Based on everything that I found, I ended with this full command: git filter-repo --path .composer-cache --path vendor --path docroot/core --path docroot/libraries --path docroot/modules/contrib --path docroot/themes/contrib --path web/libraries --invert-paths
Confirm the clean up. Execute git rev-list --objects --all and it should show that all those folders and their coment have disappeared.

The result
I believe that as a result of these changes, when I first push to the cloud repo, I will have to force:
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags

Question
Is all this correct? Am I missing anything? Am I over complicating?
Thanks,
Alex

This is counterproductive.  That history is all there for a reason.  If you really don't want the history, then why use git at all?  Just create a new, empty repo, and copy all of the files into it.

I respectfully disagree with @TimRoberts. If there's stuff in the repo that should not have been included and it is ok to rewrite history, then go for it. (Just make me the hero when you rewrite history).

But is that going to free up space?

I appreciate your comments and they are valid, although I'm not trying to erase the whole history, but only portions of that history that don't really affect me (there seems to be a bunch of caching files in the repo). This whole exercise started because my hosting company says that my code repository should not be more than 1GB (it's at 1.7GB now). In any case, I just want to know if my process is sound, if I'm missing somehing, or if there's a much simpler way to accomplish the same thing.

Can you also try to utilize the git revert -n {commit_hash}  ... This way it will unstage all the files of that commit and then simply you can select the files you want to revert from that commit while creating the new commit. This way you can revert as many as file you want from n number of commits . This may take time but it will maintain the entire history and following that you can add those extensions into the .gitignore you don't want to commit.
Else I will prefer to manually handle the situation. There could be many ways to do that manually.

Thank you @ZaidKhan but reverting will not actually remove the files. As part of the repository history, they will remain there. The idea is to keep the history while, at the same time, disappear with all the files and folder that should not have been included in the repo. My concern here is that I never did anything like this and I don't consider myself to have a profound knowledge of GIT, so I'm asking others who had the same issue to share their experience and/or to those who know and understand GIT better than me, to review my proposed steps and tell me if I'm missing anything. Thanks.
